# Can strace debug an application being debugged by gdb?

Tags: android, debugging, gdb, strace

**Background**

I'm debugging an Android application using `gdb` 8.3 under WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).  When debugging my app `gdb` frequently catches SIGSEGV and other signals that terminate the application, in general at inconsistent points in the session.  These signals do not occur when the app is run without `gdb`.  I have good reason to believe that `gdb` is the source of the instabilities.

I therefore want to monitor the running gdb-app using `strace`, in the hope of exercising the app and seeing what system function generates the offending signal when it crashes.

**The Problem**

`strace` is unable to attach to the gdb-debugged Android application because it cannot attach to an already attached process.

Here is the `gdbserver` command to attach to the running process:

```
dreamlte:/data/local/tmp # ./gdbserver :9999 --attach 26060
Attached; pid = 26060
Listening on port 9999
Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1
```

I start `gdb`, which attaches to the running application.

With gdb attached to the Android application, I attempt to attach `strace` to the application:

```
127|dreamlte:/data/local/tmp # ./strace -p 26060
attach: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...): Operation not permitted
```

I understand the problem is that the application process cannot be attached to more than once.

Is there a way to attach `strace` to a running gdb-app combination?

Comment: Strace is being enhanced to work with gdbserver. https://lists.strace.io/pipermail/strace-devel/2020-February/009346.html

Comment: Thanks for the encouraging heads-up!

Answer (score 2):

> I understand the problem is that the application process cannot be
>   attached to more than once.

Yes, this is the limitation of `ptrace()` system call, see [ERRORS section in man ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html):

```
EPERM  The specified process cannot be traced.  This could be because
       the tracer has insufficient privileges (the required
       capability is CAP_SYS_PTRACE); unprivileged processes cannot
       trace processes that they cannot send signals to or those
       running set-user-ID/set-group-ID programs, for obvious
       reasons.  Alternatively, the process may already be being
       traced, or (on kernels before 2.6.26) be init(1) (PID 1).
```

> I therefore want to monitor the running gdb-app using strace, in the
>   hope of exercising the app and seeing what system function generates
>   the offending signal when it crashes.

Instead, you can see backtrace when the app crashes. You will probably see some system function generating signal or something else you do not expect.

Comment: Although not as "pretty" as strace output, definitely a logical method -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can (at least on RHEL-like distro). See https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/03/16/extending-gdbserver-to-support-an-strace-client#extending_strace_to_support_gdbserver they explain at the end that the works is not yet merged upstream but testable in customised repo. You can still get the patch and apply in your distro so you enjoy this feature.

Answer (score 1):

On *BSD you may use the `ktrace` utility/syscall. Both `dtruss` and `truss` use `ptrace`. (DTrace itself does not require ptrace) (not to be confused with macOS ktrace util)

On Linux, try `bpftrace`, a DTrace-like utility.

These kind of tracing utilities have the added benefit of being able to see if and how the attachment of your debugger affects the debuggee. The program may not correctly handle the `Interrupted system call` errno.